# Visual Studio 2015: Application not appearing the same when run as in the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I'm sure I can't be the first to ask this question but I couldn't find an answer. I have designed the GUI of an app with the Form Designer and it looks like this:
[image: Here's how it looks in the designer]

[image: Here's how it looks when it is run]

As you can see, there are large gaps between the labels and text boxes that don't exist on the designer. I've tried locking them but to no avail...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ensure you have VS2015 Update 2 installed.  Project > Add New Item > Application Manifest File.  Remove the xml comments around the section that declares your app dpiAware.  There are more considerations, for one you'll have to think about how your ~3000 pixel wide window is going to usable on a laptop that has a display that's 1300 pixels wide.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately removing the dpiAware XML did not help. Also, the application window is only a little over 1000 pixels. Not that it really matters in this instance since I will only be using it on my laptop (1920*1080).

Comment: Your question requires too much guessing, post code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very casual, and solution is quite simple.
Please place your controls/control groups on panel controls (see in Toolbox). Then please set docking or anchor settings for panels and controls but remember, that control cannot use both - anchor and docking settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I put them on a panel but it didn't help.  I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: @luves2spooge - please group your controls, for example place 2 panels for controls with "Update!" button and second for grid. Set 'Docking' property for both to 'Top'. Now place group of controls from first panel on another separate panels: class with ComboBox on first, 'Find by Test Week' on another and 'Find by Student Number' on third. Set 'Docking' of these panels to left and lock their size (MaximumSize property). It should work.

Comment: First, thanks for taking the time to answer! I wasn't completely sure what you meant. I put one large panel docked to the top and put the 2 datagrids in, docked left. I the put another panel at the top, docked top. I then put more panels, 1 for each control ('class', combobox, 'find by test week', textbox1, 'find by student number', textbox2) and tried different docking options for these but it still did work, although the buttons are now the same size as the labels and textboxes. Sorry, I'm pretty new to all this (my first time using C# and VS).

Comment: @luves2spooge - I've made some sample solution for you, which is similiar to your screens: [click here to download from Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B417Ha49OOaSRDNnMFIyMHZMTDA/view?usp=sharing)
It is made in VS2012, but should run also in VS2015 without problems. I can understand that You are beginner in VS, but please try to obtain how Form Designer works. It's powerfull tool, which can be extended by external frameworks.

Comment: thank you for taking the time do that! I just had a quick look and now it makes more sense. I think I've got it now!

Comment: glad to hear that. and don't worry about my time - so simple and basic things take no longer than 5-10 minutes when someone is familiar with VS Form Designer.